# How to disable "add to compare" for non-registred user in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, compare

When non-registred user clicking on **add to compare** then it shows the alert for registration (with message "registration is required"). Please help.

This is my phtml file

```
<?php
     $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
     $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
     //var_dump(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName());
//get list layout
$currentCat = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getName();
//echo $currentCat;exit;
if ('Retail POS Software' == $currentCat && !$this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
   $displayMode =   'list';  
} else {
    $displayMode =  $this->getMode();
}
//get list layout end
?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
<?php if (!$this->getRequest()->isAjax()): ?>
<div id="ajax-errors" style="display: none;">
    <ul class="messages">
        <li class="error-msg">
            <ul>
                <li><span><?php echo $this->__('An error occurred, please try again later.'); ?></span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="loading" style="display: none; margin-bottom: 10px; text-align: center;">
    <img class="v-middle" alt="" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/loader-shopby.gif'); ?>"> <?php echo $this->__('Loading, please wait...'); ?>
</div>
<div id="catalog-listing">
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="category-products">

    <div class="toolbar-top">
        <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php // List mode 
        //change $this->getMode() to $displayMode
        ?>

    <div class="yt-products-container clearfix">
        <?php if($displayMode!='grid'): ?>
        <?php $_iterator = 0; ?>
        <ol class="products-list" >
            <?php 
            $count_input_qty = 0;
            foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): 
            $count_input_qty++;
            $now = date("Y-m-d");
            $newsFrom= substr($_product->getData('news_from_date'),0,10);
            $newsTo=  substr($_product->getData('news_to_date'),0,10);
            $specialprice = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSpecialPrice();
            $price = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getPrice();
            $saleoff= round(($price - $specialprice)/$price*100) ;
            ?>
            <li class="item <?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($_productCollection) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                <div class="item-inner">
                    <div class="product-list-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="product-image">
                            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product-img" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>">
                                <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
                                src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(300,300); ?>"
                                alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                            </a>

                            <?php if ( $now>=$newsFrom && $now<=$newsTo ){ ?>
                                <span class="new-product have-ico"><?php echo $this->__('New'); ?></span>
                            <?php }
                            if ( $specialprice ){ ?>
                                <span class="sale-product have-ico"><?php echo $this->__('Sale'); ?></span>
                            <?php } ?>                          
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-info col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="product-name">
                            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>">
                            <?php if( strlen($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name')) > 100 ){
                                     echo substr($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'), 0, 100);
                                } else {
                                    echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name');
                                }?>
                            </a>
                        </div>   
                        <div class="product-review">
                            <?php  echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, "short", true); ?>
                        </div>                     
                        <div class="product-price">
                            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                        </div>      

                        <?php
                            // Provides extra blocks on which to hang some features for products in the list
                            // Features providing UI elements targeting this block will display directly below the product name
                            if ($this->getChild('name.after')) {
                                $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
                                foreach ($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName) {
                                    $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
                                    $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
                                    echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml();
                                }
                            }
                        ?>

                        <?php if($_product->getshort_description()) { ?>
                        <div class="product-desciption">
                            <?php echo $_product->getshort_description();?>
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>  

                        <?php /* if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                            <?php endif; */?>
                        <div class="product-addto-wrap">
                                <div class="product-addcart">
                                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>                                    
                                        <a class="btn-cart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to cart') ?>" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')">
                                            <?php echo $this->__('Add to cart') ?>
                                        </a>                                                                    
                                    <?php endif; ?>                             
                                </div>
                                <div class="wishlist-compare">
                                    <?php if ( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() ) : ?>
                                    <a class="link-wishlist" href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>">
                                        <?php //echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>
                                    </a>
                                    <?php endif; ?>

                                    <?php if( $_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product) ): ?>

                                    <a class="link-compare" href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare'); ?>">
                                        <?php //echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?>
                                    </a>

                                    <?php endif;?>
                                </div>
                            </div>                                          
                    </div>                                                          
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('products-list', 'none-recursive')</script>

        <?php else: ?>
        <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
        <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount();?>
        <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product):?>
        <?php 
        $now = date("Y-m-d H:m:s");
        $newsFrom= $_product->getNewsFromDate();
        $newsTo=  $_product->getNewsToDate();
        $specialprice = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSpecialPrice();
        $price = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getPrice();
        $special_from_date = $_product->getSpecialFromDate();
        $special_to_date = $_product->getSpecialToDate();
        ?>
        <?php if ( $i++ == 0 ){ ?>
        <div class="products-grid">
            <div class="row">
                <?php } ?>
                <div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="item-inner">

                        <div class="product-image">
                            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                                <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
                                src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(300,300); ?>"
                                alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                            </a>

                            <?php
                            // Provides extra blocks on which to hang some features for products in the list
                            // Features providing UI elements targeting this block will display directly below the product name
                            if ($this->getChild('name.after')) {
                                $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
                                foreach ($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName) {
                                    $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
                                    $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
                                    echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml();
                                }
                            }
                            ?>

                            <?php if ( $now>=$newsFrom && $now<=$newsTo ){ ?>
                                <span class="new-product have-ico"><?php echo $this->__('New'); ?></span>
                            <?php }
                            if ( $specialprice ){ ?>
                                <span class="sale-product have-ico"><?php echo $this->__('Sale'); ?></span>
                            <?php } ?>                          
                        </div>

                        <div class="product-info">
                            <div class="product-name">
                                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>">
                                <?php if( strlen($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name')) > 60 ){
                                     echo substr($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'), 0, 60).'...more';
                                } else {
                                    echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name');
                                }?>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="product-review">
                                <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, "short", true); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="product-price">
                                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                            </div>

                            <div class="product-addto-wrap">
                                <div class="product-addcart">
                                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>

                                        <a class="btn-cart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to cart') ?>" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')">
                                            <?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>
                                        </a>

                                    <?php else: ?>
                                    <p class="availability out-of-stock">
                                        <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?> </span>
                                    </p>
                                    <?php endif; ?>                             
                                </div>
                                <div class="wishlist-compare">
                                    <?php if ( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() ) : ?>
                                    <a class="link-wishlist" href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>">
                                        <?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>
                                    </a>
                                    <?php endif; ?>

                                    <?php if( $_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product) ): ?>

                                    <a class="link-compare" href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare'); ?>">
                                        <?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?>
                                    </a>

                                    <?php endif;?>
                                </div>
                            </div>                          
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
        <?php if ( $i == $_collectionSize ){ ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <div class="toolbar-bottom">
        <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    </div>

</div>    
<?php if (!$this->getRequest()->isAjax()): ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($this->helper('sm_shopby')->isAjaxEnabled() && !$this->getRequest()->isAjax()): ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    function pushState(data, link, replace) {
        var History = window.History;
        if ( !History.enabled ) {
            return false;
        }

        if (replace) {
            History.replaceState(data, document.title, link);
        } else {
            History.pushState(data, document.title, link);
        }
    }

    function handleEvent(el, event) {
        var url, fullUrl;
        if (typeof el === 'string') {
            url = el;
        } else if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a') {
            url = $(el).readAttribute('href');
        } else if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'select') {
            url = $(el).getValue();
        }

        <?php // Add this to query string for full page caching systems ?>
        if (url.indexOf('?') != -1) {
            fullUrl = url + '&isLayerAjax=1';
        } else {
            fullUrl = url + '?isLayerAjax=1';
        }

        $('loading').show();
        $('ajax-errors').hide();

        pushState(null, url, false);

        new Ajax.Request(fullUrl, {
            method: 'get',
            onSuccess: function(transport) {
                if (transport.responseJSON) {                    
                    $('catalog-listing').update(transport.responseJSON.listing);
                    $('layered-navigation').update(transport.responseJSON.layer);
                    pushState({
                        listing: transport.responseJSON.listing,
                        layer: transport.responseJSON.layer
                    }, url, true);
                    ajaxListener();
                } else {
                    $('ajax-errors').show();
                }
                $('loading').hide();
            }
        });

        if (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
    function ajaxListener() {
        var els;
        els = $$('div.pager-wrapper a').concat(
            $$('div.sort-by-wrap a'),
            $$('div.view-mode-wrap a'),
           // $$('div.pager select'),
            $$('div.sorter select'),
            $$('div.block-layered-nav a')
        );
        els.each(function(el) {
            if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a') {
                $(el).observe('click', function(event) {
                    handleEvent(this, event);
                });
            } else if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'select') {
                $(el).setAttribute('onchange', '');
                $(el).observe('change', function(event) {
                    handleEvent(this, event);
                });
            }
        });
    }
    document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
        ajaxListener();

        (function(History) {
            if ( !History.enabled ) {
                return false;
            }

            pushState({
                listing: $('catalog-listing').innerHTML,
                layer: $('layered-navigation').innerHTML
            }, document.location.href, true);

            // Bind to StateChange Event
            History.Adapter.bind(window, 'popstate', function(event) {
                if (event.type == 'popstate') {
                    var State = History.getState();
                    $('catalog-listing').update(State.data.listing);
                    $('layered-navigation').update(State.data.layer);
                    ajaxListener();
                }
            });
        })(window.History);
    });
    //]]>
</script>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($this->getRequest()->isAjax()){ ?>


<?php } ?>

<?php
// Provides a block where additional page components may be attached, primarily good for in-page JavaScript
if ($this->getChild('after')) {
    $_afterChildren = $this->getChild('after')->getSortedChildren();
    foreach ($_afterChildren as $_afterChildName) {
        $_afterChild = $this->getChild('after')->getChild($_afterChildName);
        //set product collection on after blocks
        $_afterChild->setProductCollection($_productCollection);
        echo $_afterChild->toHtml();
    }
}
?>
```

**Updated:**
@AmitBera Sir, I have made changes in my compare button like this. please tell me where i goes wrong.

```
      <?php 
       if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
     <?php if( $_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product) ): ?>

                                <a class="link-compare" href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare'); ?>">
                                    <?php //echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?>
                                </a>

                                <?php endif;?>
                                }
                                else
                                {
        <?php echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Registration is required for compare product"); </script>?>

      }
             ?>
```

Comment: please specify magento version?

Comment: i am using magento 1.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple,you can do this

Rewrite  helper class `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_Compare`

At  that override class at `getAddToCompareUrl`  add  this condition

```
if(!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()){
         return '';
    }
```

**Rewrite class may be like this:**

```
<?php
[ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Helper_Catalog_Product_Compare extends Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_Compare
public function getAddUrl($product)
    {
    /* If Customer is no loggedin then return '' url */
    if(!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()){
         return '';
    }
        if ($this->_logCondition->isVisitorLogEnabled() || $this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            return $this->_getUrl('catalog/product_compare/add', $this->_getUrlParams($product));
        }
        return '';
    }
}
```

### Full module

Module main config file `Stackexchange_Corewrite.xml`

**location:app/etc/modules/**

**Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Stackexchange_Corewrite>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Stackexchange_Corewrite>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**Module config file** *config.xml*

**location:** `app/code/local/Stackexchange/Corewrite/etc`

**code**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Stackexchange_Corewrite>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Stackexchange_Corewrite>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <corewrite>
        <class>Stackexchange_Corewrite_Helper</class>
      </corewrite>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product_compare>Stackexchange_Corewrite_Helper_Catalog_Product_Compare</product_compare>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </helpers>
  </global>
</config>
```

**rewrite class file** Compare.php

location: `app/code/local/Stackexchange/Corewrite/Helper/Catalog/Product`

**code**

```
<?php
class Stackexchange_Corewrite_Helper_Catalog_Product_Compare extends Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_Compare
{
    public function getAddUrl($product)
    {
    if(!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()){
         return ''; 
    }
        if ($this->_logCondition->isVisitorLogEnabled() || $this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            return $this->_getUrl('catalog/product_compare/add', $this->_getUrlParams($product));
        }
        return '';
    }
}
```

**edited**

**find the code at phtml flies**

```
  <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                                    <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
```

**Change it:**

```
<?php 
    if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){ ?>
         <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                                <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
<?php    }else{
       echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Registration is required for compare product"); </script>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: download code from  http://jmp.sh/o4khnzU and just  put in magento folder

Comment: this file may be blocked or may contain virus

Comment: Swati, i already posted the answer. I don't know why u did not implement this . Just add a if condition where compare link is called `if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){  ..`  add to compare button/link code  `}`

Comment: simple syntax issue..  i have updated it

Comment: Is module required for this?

Comment: Not required this extension

Answer (score 2):

Got solution after long time.

I have added following code at the place of compare button

```
<?php if( $_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product) ): ?>
                                <?php if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) { ?>
                                <a class="link-compare" href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare'); ?>"></a>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                            <a class="link-compare loginToCompare" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare'); ?>"></a>
                            <?php } ?>
                                <?php endif;?>
```

and added following jquery at the bottom of page for redirection of login page or create account

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $(".loginToCompare").click(function(){
        var r = confirm("You can not compare product without registration please click ok to login or create account!");
        if (r == true) {
             window.location.href="/customer/account/login/";
        }       
    });
});
```

this is really working for me. thanks to everyone who help me